# Looping in the while function when conditions have already been met?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am creating a savings simulator and now I need to incorporate try and except statements in the code. After doing so, my code became buggy and I restarted. Now, the while loop in the middle keeps repeating even though the conditions have been met.

```
reachZero = False
investRemain = 0

while reachZero == False:

try:
    investAmt = float(input("How much to invest? ")) + investRemain

    try:
        investRate = float(input("Invest rate? ")) / 100 +1

        try:
            investYear = float(input("How many years? "))

            done = False
            yearIncrements = 0

            while yearIncrements <= investYear:
                investAmt = investAmt * investRate
                yearIncrements = yearIncrements + 1

                str_investAmt = str(round(investAmt,2))
                str_yearIncrements = str(yearIncrements)
                print("After", str_yearIncrements, "years, you have", str_investAmt)

                try:
                    withdraw = float(input("How much to withdraw? "))
                    investAmt = investAmt - withdraw
                    investRemain == investAmt

                    if investAmt == 0:
                        print("Withdrawn all money.")
                        reachZero = True

                except:
                    print("Invalid.")


        except:
            print("Invalid.")

    except:
        print("Invalid.")

except:
    print("Invalid.")
```

I tried adding a break in there to see if that would help, but it didn't.

Comment: A `while` loop keeps repeating *because* the conditions have been met. Did you misunderstand what a `while` loop is doing?

Comment: Please read some tutorials about `try`/`except` in python. This is *not* how you use it correctly